# How to reset partitions after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I have yesterday uninstalled Ubuntu from my Dual-boot PC (Win 7). I first deleted the partitions used by Ubuntu using Windows, then wanted to restart but ofcourse `grub` couldn't be found. And as if it couldn't get any better, I didn't have a recovery disc. So after using Hiren's BootCD 15.2 to boot up Windows, I made a restore-cd for Windows and then used that to reset the MBR. (I am aware this could have been done directly from HBCD, but I couldn't figure out how). So now Windows boots again, but I have quite a few partitions that are doing nothing now.

I read that using `GParted` gives more options than the Windows disk manager or whatever, so I'm using Ubuntu on USB now so I can use this tool. This is what I get when opening it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsZ5H.jpg

Now, it's all one big drive, but I only want a C:/ (labeled OS) and a D:/ (labeled DATA), as I had before installing Ubuntu. The data on the other partitions I presume are purely from Ubuntu-data, and can therefore be deleted.

Since I've had enough misery only getting my MBR to work, I'm really want to make sure I don't mess my computer up again.

How do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply deleting the linux partitions (`/dev/sd3-6-7`) is totally safe for you. But this will leave some empty space in your disk.

You might then want to resize your 2 NTFS partitions so that they take up the whole space.
**Be careful here :** Your partitions have a lot of data, and such operation might corrupt part of it. But also, it would imply moving **the head of your partitions**. If the resizing fails and this head is corrupted, your partitions would not be recognized any more by the BIOS for booting, and you'll need to use some recovery tool to get it back.

**If you don't want to take the risk**, you may simply delete those linux partitions using GParted, and then create new partitions from Windows tool and use them for other purposes.
As an example, you may [move your `PAGEFILE.SYS` to a separate partition](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_pagefilesys_and_can_i_move_it.html) to free space in your `C:` drive.
There are always means to make use of a 35GB partition.

Comment: I have already deleted the partitions using the Windows Disk Manager of whatever it's called. This created my initial grub-error. But what I don't understand is that the head of my partition must be moved. I understand that my data should be in the beginning of the partition. But when installing Ubuntu, didn't it just take space at the end of my partition? Would seem more logical to me, otherwise it had to move all the data, no?

Comment: @arbitter What I told was based on the asumption that your screenshot reflected your disk current state. Given what GParted shows you, it looks like Ubuntu moved your partitions around when installing itself. Also, your grub error came from the fact that by deleting the partition, you deleted part of GRUB data.

Comment: It is the current state - I did 'delete' them though in Windows, not that that did anything spectacular. It does indeed look like Ubuntu moved them around, because I only used space from 1 partition initially, but can't remember how much. However, if Ubuntu can move it around, cant I as well and avoid needing to 'rewrite' all the data to the beginning of the partition?

Comment: @arbitter I don't know what is GParted exact behaviour, but I don't think it'll move everything if it's not needed. But when talking about the **head of partition**, it's not the data at the beginning of it I'm talking about, but the metadata of your partition, which tells everything that the partition exists and what are its properties. If nothing happens, resizing your partition should be ok. I already lost partitions while trying to resize them by moving the beginning, so I tend to be careful about that. Maybe too much, I don't know.

Comment: Aaaaah I see, thats a good heads up!